# Problems in using T-SQL (Data Access Layer) in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I am a learner of MVC (4). I have gone through some tutorials on MVC 4. Those are simply awesome. But all of those have used EF with LINQ to SQL for database operation. If i want to use T-SQL for database operation, how can i do it? Should i write sql query in Model or in another library? Where will i place my data access layer?

I googled with this question. But no satisfactory technique found.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement my TSQL when I first started doing MVC4 & WPF/WCF. TBH the number of hours I wasted I was probably better off learning the Linq I now know sooner.

I found that if I created a good level of relationships in my database I was able to easily achieve in Linq what I could in TSQL.